# One Definition Rule - compilation

Tags: c++, g++, one-definition-rule

I am trying to understand ODR.
I created one file pr1.cpp like this:

```
struct S{
  int a;
};
```

a second file pr2.cpp like this

```
struct S {
  char  a;
};
```

and a main file like this :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
  return 0;
}
```

I am compiling using terminal with the command :

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra pr1.cpp pr2.cpp main.cpp -o mypr
```

The compiler does not find any kind of error BUT there are two declarations of the type "S"...I am not understanding what is really happening..I thought to get an error after the "linkage" phase because of the ODR violation..
I can get the error only editing the main.cpp file adding :

```
#include "pr1.cpp"
#include "pr2.cpp"
```

Can anyone exmplain me what is happening?

Comment: I assume the code is discarded because you never create either object.

Comment: [The behavior is undefined.](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#6.sentence-4)

Comment: POD structures are really just a compile-time thing, and if they're not used no trace of them will be found in the object or executable files. It *is* technically *undefined behavior* since you define two different structure with the same name (actually just changing spacing is enough to make them different, even if the members were otherwise the same).

Comment: The behaviour is formally undefined.   But behaving in a way that seems completely reasonable and error free is one possible effect of undefined behaviour.

Comment: fyi The ODR rule is there because compiler only sees one compilation unit (cpp file) at a time.  It is easy to break the ODR rule and not have the compiler ever see the problem.  It is up to you not to break this rule as in most cases the compiler can not diagnose a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless you include both definitions in the same file, there is no problem. This is because the compiler operates on a single translation unit which is usually a .cpp file. Everything you `#include` in this file is also part of the translation unit because the preprocessor basically copies and pastes the contents of all included files.

What happens is that the compiler will create and object file (.obj usually) for each translation unit and then the linker will create a single executable (or .dll etc) by linking all the object files and the libraries the project depends on. In your case the compiler encountered each struct in a different translation unit so it doesn't see a problem. When you include both files, the two definitions now find themselves in the same translation unit and the compiler throws an error because it cannot resolve the ambiguity if an `S` is used in this translation unit (even though you don't have to use one for the program to be ill-formed).

As a side-note, do not include .cpp files in other .cpp files. I'm sure you can find a lot on how to organize your code in header and source files and it doesn't directly answer the question so I won't expand on it.

EDIT: I neglected to say why you didn't get a linker error. Some comments have pointed out that this is undefined behavior which means that even though your linker should probably complain it doesn't actually have to. In your case you have one .obj file for each struct and a main.obj. None of these references the other so the linker does not see any references that it needs to resolve and it probably doesn't bother checking for ambiguous symbols.

I assume most linkers would throw an error if you declared `struct S;` and tried to use a `S*` or `S&` (an actual `S` would require definition inside the same translation unit). That is because the linker would need to resolve that symbol and it would find two matching definitions. Given that this is undefined, though, a standard-compliant linker could just pick one and silently link your program into something nonsensical because you meant to use the other. This can be especially dangerous for structs that get passed around from one .cpp to the other as the definition needs to be consistent. It might also be a problem when identically named structs/classes are passed through library boundaries. Always avoid duplicating names for these reasons.

Comment: You're not answering why the linker doesn't complain about the 2 definitions I think.

Comment: I was going to but I decided to remove that part because I felt the OP was specifically about the compilation.

Comment: My bad I somehow missed the reference to the linking phase in the OP

Comment: @patatahooligan I would be glad to you if you can also explain this, I am finding all of this very interesting!

Comment: Regardless of the mechanics of compiling and linking, the code violates the one definition rule, and its behavior is undefined. The results may well be innocuous (as here), but they can also be disastrous.